# PHP, using Ajax not working calling php file in other directory

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Main.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    searchUser();
});

function searchUser() {
    alert("aaaaaaaa");
    var data = $("#user-search-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert("bbbbbbbb");
            }
    });

    alert("cccccccc");

    return false;
}
```

test.php

```
<?php echo "testing 1234" ?>
```

Directory:

- phpturtorial/admin/main.php
- phptutorial/admin/test.php

I am calling php function using ajax but not working. My code able to alert "aaaaaaaa" and "cccccccc" but cannot alert "bbbbbbbb". Any idea ? is it related to my incorrect path ?

Comment: try to pass resposnse in json from `test.php` file

Comment: Do you have two folders `phpturtorial` and `phptutorial` or is it just a typo?

Comment: @VinayKaklotar thank you for your reply. tested to pass response in json from test.php no response from the json.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for your reply.  Tested with inspect element, on network console show incorrect URL, the correct URL is phptutorial/admin/test.php

Comment: Your response is still unclear. I understand that the correct URL for `test.php` is `phptutorial/admin/test.php`. What is the correct URL for `main.php`? What URL does the network console show being used for `test.php` when you get the problem?

Comment: Is `phpturtorial` a typo?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  ajax URL value must  url: "phptutorial/admin/test.php" instead of url: "test.php".

Comment: Then that's what you should use in the url parameter for your Ajax call...

Comment: Since we still haven't gotten an answer for the simple question "is it a typo", I'm out...

Comment: Some people do their very best to avoid being helped.

Comment: @ShinnL, the answer to this is very simple for people to provide, once the information is all given. There are three questions here that were never really answered. To get the most out of this site, you might want to work on how to fully answer the questions that people ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phpturtorial/admin/main.php` and `phptutorial/admin/test.php` are in two different directories. 
Hence why it is not able to locate `test.php`.

Change `url: "test.php"` to `url: "/phptutorial/admin/test.php"`

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks for pointing that out, completely forgot about that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## With the Given Information:

**Case 1:**

> You need to modify the ajax request url *slightly*.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    searchUser();
});

function searchUser() {
    alert("aaaaaaaa");
    var data = $("#user-search-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "phptutorial/admin/test.php", //or the path to test.php
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert("bbbbbbbb");
            }
    });

    alert("cccccccc");

    return false;
}
```

**Case 2:**

> Provided path could be wrong as they are identical.